# How to add arbitrary content to R package using vignette?

Tags: r, makefile, r-package

How, if at all, can one use R package vignettes to generate arbitrary files for inclusion in the installed package?

I have two concrete use-cases and approaches I have been tinkering with today.

First, I have a template Excel file which I wish to populate with data derived in a (Sweave) vignette, and then provide this modified Excel file in the package (alongside the template).  Following convention, the template is in the `inst/extdata` directory of the source package; the vignette contains some code which reads this using `system.file` and then writes the modified copy back to the same directory.  However, while the vignette (and package) builds successfully with `R CMD build`, after `R CMD INSTALL` of the tarball the `extdata` directory of the installed package does not contain the modified file, only the template.

The second use-case is more general, and involves Makefiles.  I want to render the vignette(s) to both PDF and HTML format from the .tex files.  The HTML versions I want to create using `make4ht`, and are actually provided for ingestion by another application, rather than for use in the package *per se*; therefore I don't want them in the `doc` directory with the PDF vignettes -- let's put them in `outputs`.

Currently I am trying to use a Makefile for this purpose.  In the `vignettes` directory of the source package, I have a very rudimentary Makefile like the following:

```
all : foo.tex
    make4ht foo.tex
    mkdir ../outputs
    mv foo.html ../outputs
    texi2pdf foo.tex
    rm foo.tex
```

The expected behaviour on `R CMD build` is:

1. Create the HTML version of the vignette `foo.html` with `make4ht`
2. Create a directory for it called `outputs` directly under the R package root
3. Move the HTML file there
4. Create the PDF vignette proper
5. Clean up the .tex file to avoid errors about duplicated vignette entries

Then on `R CMD INSTALL` of the resulting tarball, I would expect to find a directory `outputs` under the installed package, containing the file `foo.html`.  However, this is not the case -- the PDF and source vignettes are there, but there is no sign of `outputs`.

I understand that packages are installed to a temporary directory for the purpose of building vignettes.  I assume that none of the files written to this temporary location are actually incorporated into the final package, except files like `vignettes/*.pdf` or `vignettes/*.html`.  So, with this context, let me repeat my question:

Is it possible to create (arbitrary) files for inclusion in a package using vignettes?

I am aware that all of this could be done prior to package-building, putting files somewhere under `inst`.  But I would prefer to have it all done in a single step if possible; the vignettes are documenting various aspects of data analysis, and I want to provide the outputs of this analysis in the final package, so it seems a natural workflow.

Comment: One can---a few packages use precomputed pdf vignettes which are then (with a short latex trick) slurped in the Sweave vignette Rnw file.  See https://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2019/01/11/add-a-static-pdf-vignette-to-an-r-package/  Otherwise as you say, one can also 'hide' example scripts away in `inst/`.  Otherwise your overall issue is that R wants _everything_ rebuilt at package build time which conflicts with your setup here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't do that, and it doesn't really make sense to try.  Vignettes are supposed to be runnable by users to duplicate the results you got, or to make small changes to see how they work out.  Users shouldn't expect that to change the contents of the package.

If you want your vignette to produce files for the user, they should by default be in the temporary directory, so they won't make permanent changes to the user's file system.

I think the approach in your final paragraph is the only way that will work.  You run some Makefile before building the package, and perhaps it runs the vignette to install files into `inst` somewhere.  One way to do this would be for your vignette to look at environment variables to find the destination where it puts its file.  Your Makefile can set the env var before it processes the vignette.  But if a user (or the `R CMD build` system) runs your vignette without that env var, the files won't be produced, or will be deleted at the end of the run.

Comment: Thanks -- this answers the question and improves my understanding of the limited scope of vignettes.  I have since discovered the `vignettes/.install_extras` file which will at least allow me to add arbitrary content to the package `doc/` directory, but I get that I shouldn't abuse this to add files not required for documentation purposes.